# Row to column Not column to row - Pivot 1 row to multiple columns using T SQL

Tags: t-sql, pivot

I have data in a table that I want to pivot from 1 row to multiple
columns. I only want the columns with dx to pivot if there is a value in
them. Thanks.

This is a sample of what I have:

| NBR | dx | dx2 | dx3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | j2 |  | e4 |

This is what I want:

| NBR | Diag |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | j2 |
| 11 | e4 |

Comment: I am not sure who/what you were quoting here, so I've removed the quote blocks. If none of this is your own content then you **need** to cite the source per the referencing guidelines and then add your own content to the post.